# Fire a method when click an Enter key

Tags: angularjs

```
<form novalidate name="frm1" autocomplete="off">

   //UI elements                               

   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6">
      <button ng-click="MyFunc()">Next Step</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Can you tell me how to fire `MyFunc()` method when click the `enter key`.On the above form where there is no submit button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should bind the submit event of form. And if you don't specify type then  default behaviour of button is submit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have written below mentioned directive and it works.

**Directive :**

```
angular.module('app.directives')
    .directive('ngEnter', function () { //a directive to 'enter key press' in elements with the "ng-enter" attribute

        return function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                if (event.which === 13) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        };
    })
```

**HTML**

```
<form novalidate name="frm1" autocomplete="off">

   //UI elements      
 <input name="userName" type="text" ng-enter="MyFunc()"/>                         

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6">
      <button ng-click="MyFunc()">Next Step</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You could also call it ngEnterOrClick and add an additional call to 

`element.bind('mouseup', function(event) {
    ....
}`

which relieves you from having to have both ng-click and ng-enter with the same logic.

Answer (score 37):

Try this:

```
<input ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? MyFunc() : null" >
```

At form level you can use this:

```
<form ng-submit="myFunc()" ...>
```

Comment: Do I need to give above on each and every ui element within that form ?

Comment: @Sampath:- Yes you have to!

Comment: Don't we have a method to use on `form` level ?

Comment: Without a `submit` button above one is not working ?

Comment: @Sampath:- Did you tried this: `<form ng-submit="myFunc()" novalidate name="frm1" autocomplete="off">` ?

Comment: yes,But it's not working due to I don't have a submit button.What if I change my button type as `submit` ? Will it have any other issues ?

Comment: @Sampath:- I dont think it will have any issues, you can give it a try!

Comment: Thanks a for supporting.But `submit` button solution is not working.I have written a directive.I'll update it later.

Comment: Doesn't work for my Angular Material input field inside `mat-form-field`. I get `... not allowed here` for both `ng-keyup` and `ng-submit`

Answer (score 6):

Simply write (keyup.enter)="your_function_name()" in your html file in same way you write (click).
Below is a code snippet.
`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="modelSearchedData" (keyup.enter)="getModelList()">`

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is binding your function on submit event instead of enter key. You should not focus on enter, because for exemple on the iPhone there is a keyboard button to execute form, which behave like enter but is not enter event ... and the iPhone is just one exemple :D

So you should change your `<button>` by an input `<type="submit"/>`
This way `enter key` will automatically fire the form submit event.

Then in your submit event, `return false;` to prevent HTML action (which send the form) and execute your code.

HTML

```
<form novalidate name="frm1" autocomplete="off">
 //UI elements                               
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6">
      <input type="submit" value="Next Step" />
   </div>
 </form>
```

JS

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    MyFunc();
    return false;
});
```

I hope this answer your question.

PS : you can use ng-submit instead of jQuery selector, if you do not want to use jQuery.

Comment: if you don't specify type then default behaviour of button is submit

Comment: Will it have any other issues if I do so ? I mean when I change the type as `submit`.

Comment: No other difference, except this is a way more clean way to do in term of accessibility (which is important :D), because your action is related to a meaning, not to en event.

Comment: Thanks a for supporting.But `submit` button solution is not working.I have written a directive.I'll update it later.

Comment: This is not the angular way, avoid mixing jQuery unless you absolutely have to

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that does not require a directive. I was already using ng-change to capture each keypress and perform a search, but clicking Enter would throw my SharePoint page into Edit mode. SharePoint doesn't let you access the form tag, so most of these solutions didn't work for me.

This solution was much simpler and kept my code in the same place, I have an ng-change AND an ng-keypress event that point to the same event handler, vm.txtSearchChange():

**HTML**

```
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" style="width: 400px;" ng-change="vm.txtSearchChange()" 
ng-keypress="$event.keyCode == 13 ? vm.txtSearchChange($event) : null" 
ng-model="vm.Search" ng-model-options="{debounce: 200}"/>
```

Note the ng-change event does not pass the $event attribute, and handles the legitimate key presses, while the ng-keypress event is only for the enter key.

**SCRIPT**

```
vm.txtSearchChange = function ($event) {
  if ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  console.log("Search: " + vm.Search);
  vm.showResults();
}   // end vm.txtSearchChange
```

When $event is not null, it's the enter key, we call preventDefault() and don't process further. When $event is null, it's a valid key, and we pass it along to vm.showResults() for processing.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here involve additional workarounds that simply are not needed, you can work with the standard form submission by making these two small changes and the Enter key will function as desired.

- Move the ng-click from the button to the form, and make it an ng-submit
- Add a type="submit" to the button

For more complex forms with multiple buttons you might need to try some of the workarounds, but for the majority of cases this will work.

```
<form novalidate name="frm1" autocomplete="off" ng-submit="MyFunc()">

   //UI elements                               

   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6">
      <button type="submit">Next Step</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="Inputvalue" id="Inputvalue" ng-change="EnableDisableCheckButton()" ng-model="enteredInputValue" ng-disabled="isDisabledInputvalueTextbox" ng-blur="" data-ng-keypress="onEnterKeyPress($event)" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="isDisabledCheckButton" ng-click="ValidateInputvalue()">Check</button>
```

And in your JavaScript file, add below:

```
  $scope.onEnterKeyPress = function (event) {
        if (event.charCode == 13) //if enter is hot then call ValidateInputvalue().
            $scope.ValidateInputvalue();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This example worked for me:

HTML Code:

```
<input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchString" ng-change="startSearch()" ng-keypress="$event.keyCode == 13 ? startSearch($event) : null">
```

Typescript:

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  startSearch(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.code === "Enter") {
      //Code that you need to run
    }
  }
```

https://go.tiny.cloud/blog/angular-5-tutorial-step-step-guide-first-angular-5-app/